# How to maintain the value of label after postback in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

In asp.net page I need to know how to maintain the value of a particular label assign by the html button click. After postback done.

Detailed code:

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">Before Changing</asp:Label></td>

            <td><asp:Label id="lbl2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label></td>

            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

</tr>

        <tr>
            <td><asp:Button ID="btnasp" runat="server"  Text="ASP Button" Height="50px" Width="150px" OnClick="btnasp_Click"/></td>

            <td><input type="button" id="btnhtml" value="HTML Button" onclick="showlabel()"  style="height:50px; width:150px"/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function showlabel() {
        $('#lbl1').text("After Changing");

        }
</script>
```

cs code

```
   protected void btnasp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtbox.Text = lbl1.Text;
    }
```

OutPut

[image]

If I click HTML button the label text before changing is change to after changing. Then I click the ASP button after changing value is show in textbox.

This is done without adding value in hidden field and not using the server control to html button. How is this possible?

Comment: i really wish I knew what you were asking...

Comment: @ T McKeown If I Confisued You ..?

Comment: @Gurunathan For future reference - questions are easier to read if you use sentence case and not [title case](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/capital_letters_title_case.htm).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `label` is converted into a `span` element and the html elements, like `span` or `div`, do not have `ViewState`.  Neither the text or html of these is sent 
server side like `form` elements.

Form elements that are posted are the input elements as well as `hidden` fields. ASP.net maintains ViewState using hidden field and input elements.

I am afraid you have to use hidden fields to maintain the value of labels between postbacks.

**HTML**

```
<input id="hdnLabelState" type="hidden" runat="server" >
```

*Javascript*

```
document.getElementById('<%= hdnLabelState.ClientID %>').value = "changed value of span";
```

*Server side (code behind)*

```
string changedLabelValue = hdnLabelState.Value;
```

Comment: Thank You For Your Solution .But I'm Confisued How to Implement Is Code Into My Code Give Above . I'm Beginner For .net So Plz Tell ...

Comment: I Need This With Out Hidden Field....

Comment: Could you explain why you need without hidden field?

Comment: i cant use hiddenfield for every label controls

Comment: You can use single hidden field for all the labels, like label1:label1value, label2:label2value and extract them on server side. The same principle is used by asp.net for maintaining viewstate

Comment: I Try To  Find Out Alternate Way . With Out Using Hidden Field

Comment: You can then send the change through ajax call, but that is bit lengthy and more complex procedure.