# div appears after every postback and page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, fadeout

Hi am trying to show the result of operation performed on aspx page on using a div containing the label .. I have used JQuery to show this message with fade-out effect ..

The message appears properly and fade-out properly, but when there is any postback or refresh on that particular page the most recent message for that div appears.

aspx design code:

```
  <div class="notification-success" id="dvMsgSuccess" runat="server" visible="false">
        <i class="fa fa-check">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblMsgSuccess" runat="server"></asp:Label></i>
  </div>
```

css :

```
.notification-success {
background-color: #13AD58;
line-height: 50px;
width: 35%;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;
min-height: 40px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 18px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
```

}

JQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#<%=dvMsgSuccess.ClientID%>').fadeOut(5000, function () {
             $(this).html(""); //reset label after fadeout
         });
     });


</script>
```

When any operation is performed, am showing any messages

```
dvMsgSuccess.Visible = true;
lblMsgSuccess.Text = "operation successfull...!!!";
```

Any help Is appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: What is the requirement ?

Comment: the div "dvMsgSuccess" appears unnecessarily when page is refreshed or any postback occures

Answer (score 0):

Try:- (By Default Div is hidden through inline CSS)

```
<div class="notification-success" id="dvMsgSuccess" style="display:none;" >
        <i class="fa fa-check">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblMsgSuccess" runat="server"></asp:Label></i>
</div>
```

In any operation, call script before server method as follow:-

```
$("#dvMsgSuccess").css("display","block");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).html("")` replaces the asp.net label html, which will be rebuilt by asp.net during a postback, because Asp.net does not track changes made by jquery.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907112/how-to-maintain-the-value-of-label-after-postback-in-asp-net) question for more information