# How to POSTBACK List ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, bulletedlist

```
  <asp:BulletedList AppendDataBoundItems="true" Id="drpBankAccounts" 
                                 CssClass="sortable" runat="server">
   </asp:BulletedList/>
```

I am changing BulletedList Item's text and attributes value from clientSide. But on POSTBACK Nothings changes. And yes I am already using `!IsPostBack`. Kindly help me I just want to postback this `List` as it is.

Comment: Well - show code where you are changing and submitting the values clientside, because showing us the definition of a server side control is not illustrating your problem

Comment: A BulletedList, like a Label, is not an input control. As a consequence, it is not posted back to the server. If you want to keep track of the changes that you make to the items of the list in client code, you can use hidden fields (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907112/how-to-maintain-the-value-of-label-after-postback-in-asp-net, http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/688912/ASP-label-value-assigned-in-client-side-not-appear).