# Change Label value in aspx page from ascx page when the save button is clicked on the acsx page

Tags: asp.net, ascx

I have a label in my aspx which displays a number which has been set. Now this number can be changed from a usercontrol(ascx) which updates the value in DB. But when I click the save button on Usercontrol(ascx) I want the updated value to be set in the label which is in the aspx page.
I tried the below code to reload the page but it clears all the filters which I don't want.

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reloading simply clears and refreshes the aspx page. labels are only designed to be changed at the server side, so any client side is  not going to be sent back to the server. you have to use hidden fields to retain the value of labels between postbacks as explained here: [How to maintain the value of label after postback in Asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907112/how-to-maintain-the-value-of-label-after-postback-in-asp-net)

**HTML**

`<input id="hdnLabelState" type="hidden" runat="server" >`

**Javascript**

`document.getElementById('<%= hdnLabelState.ClientID %>').value = "changed value of span";`

**Server side (code behind)**

`string changedLabelValue = hdnLabelState.Value;`