# How to get label info on button event

Tags: c#, json, button, label

I'm trying to develop a website with webforms that saves user info on a sql server database.

To get the user location I used this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('https://geoip-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=?')
       .done(function (location) {
           $('#country').html(location.country_name);
           $('#state').html(location.state);
           $('#city').html(location.city);
           $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
           $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
           $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);
          
       });
</script>
```

It shows correctly the data on labels like

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="country"></asp:Label>
```

But when I try to get the info from the control with a button event, I get an empty string. I test sending the info to a Textbox before doing the INSERT query to sql server.

The control for testing is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The button event

```
 protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     TextBox3.Text = country.Text;
     ...
    }
```

Inside that event I call the sql query, it works fine and inserts other parameters like "project", "user" and "date_time"

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("****");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[table5]
       ([project]
       ,[user_task]
       ,[task_status]
       ,[user_ip]
       ,[user_country]
       ,[user_state]
       ,[user_city]
       ,[user_latitude]
       ,[user_longitude]
       ,[date_time])
 VALUES
       ('" + txtProject.Text + "', '" + txtUser.Text + "', '" + txtStatus.Text + "', '" + txtIP.Text + "', '" + country.Text+ "', '" + state.Text + "', '" + city.Text + "', '" + latitude.Text + "', '" + longitude.Text + "', '" + now + "')", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the insert logic and any sql used, or EF if that's what you have. What is TextBox3.Text? Are you using webforms? Something else? We need more info. The lifecycle of postbacks is a big thing for webforms.

Comment: I edited the question to include more info. In the browser console, I can get the info doing something like "var city = document.getElementById("city").textContent" but I'm not sure how to get the info from the button event

Comment: I see. Labels don't have something that they postback - they don't have viewstate. [Use a hidden input for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907112/how-to-maintain-the-value-of-label-after-postback-in-asp-net). Also, please use [parameterized queries](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx). That's a very dangerous insert and open to attack.

Comment: I replaced the sql code to include parameters. Also I changed the Labels to hidden Inputs, but it remains the same, I can't get the location info.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to change to use val for hidden

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me.

```
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormsFrameworkApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.getJSON('https://geoip-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=?')
            .done(function (location) {
                console.log(location);
                $('#country').val(location.country_name);
               
            });
    </script>

    <br /><br />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="country" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnStart" runat="server" OnClick="btnStart_Click" Text="Click me" />
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox><br />
</asp:Content>



public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox3.Text = country.Value;
    }
}
```